# How can I input an N-dimensional-input into a Tensorflow Lite model on Android?

Tags: android, image, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

- I created a Tensorflow model which takes a single 700x700 48-dimension "image" as an input (input shape is `{1, 700, 700, 48}`).
- To do so, I used Numpy's `numpy.concatenate([array_of_images], -1)`, when `array_of_images` is an array of 16 700x700 `JPEG` images.
- I converted the model to Tensorflow Lite and I'm running it on Android.
- No conversion errors or anything - all ops are valid and supported.

My question is - where in Android (or how) can I create an N-dimensional object (or container) and use it as an input to the model?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 16 RGB images,

on android you load your bitmaps into image tensors like this :

`var bitmap1 = Bitmap.load( from anywhere )
var tImage1 = TensorImage(DataType.FLOAT32)
tImage1.load(bitmap1)`

for each image,

then

`input  = arrayof(tImage1.buffer, tImage2.buffer,........tImage16.buffer)
interpreteur.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(arrayOf(input), output)`

i'm not sure but this can give you an idea

Comment: That makes the input an array of 16 images, each image 3 (or 4) dimensions. I'm interested in a single image input, which will have multiple (N) dimensions.